# How can I print items from a tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, iteration

I got the tuple -

```
Result = [
    ('80407', 'about power supply of opertional amplifier', '11 hours ago'),
    ('80405', '5V Regulator Power Dissipation', '11 hours ago')]
```

I want to iterate over the tuples and separate the items in the tuples by `;`.

The output should be as follows -

```
80407;about power supply of opertional amplifier;11 hours ago
```

I tried the following:

```
for item in zip(*Result):
    print(*item[0], end=';')
```

Which gave me the result -

```
8 0 4 0 7;a b o u t   p o w e r   s u p p l y   o f   o p e r t i o n a l   a m p l i f i e r;1 1   h o u r s   a g o;
```

and

```
for item in Result:
    print(*item[0], end=';')
```

Which gave me -

```
8 0 4 0 7;8 0 4 0 5;
```

How to properly iterate over a tuple?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Join the items in the tuple with a `;`, and join the resultant string in the outer list with another separator,  perhaps a newline `\n`

```
s = '\n'.join(';'.join(lst) for lst in Result)
print(s)
```

The output will be

```
80407;about power supply of opertional amplifier;11 hours ago
80405;5V Regulator Power Dissipation;11 hours ago
```

Answer (score 4):

To accomplish this, no `zip` call is required. Instead, your could can look like this:

```py
for item in Result:
    print(*item, sep=';')
```

You were attempting to use `end` instead of `sep`. `end` just adds a semicolon to the end of the line, instead of a newline. `sep` specifies what seperates the values in a print call. By default, this is a space (`sep=' '`) and (`end='\n'`)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not think about `sep=`. But your answer works of course as well!

Answer (score 4):

I'd join each item in the tuple with a semicolon, and then the tuples with linebreaks:

```
print('\n'.join(';'.join(i) for i in Result))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%s` and tuple position to achieve it.

```py
for i in Result:
    print('%s;%s;%s'% (i[0],i[1],i[2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using single `join` statement

```
result = [
    ('80407', 'about power supply of operational amplifier', '11 hours ago'),
    ('80405', '5V Regulator Power Dissipation', '11 hours ago')]

for item in result:
  print(';'.join(item))
```

gives

```
80407;about power supply of operational amplifier;11 hours ago
80405;5V Regulator Power Dissipation;11 hours ago
```